# How to fix checkboxes and radiobuttons display on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

They work great on PC, Mac OS and Android, but look checked/wrong on iOS devices - see images below.
Live example - http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/documentation/tutorial-components.html#checkbox-row.

Checkbox related CSS:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.checkbox .checkbox-material {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.checkbox .checkbox-material:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: scale3d(2.3, 2.3, 1);
}
.checkbox .checkbox-material .check {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .54);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkbox .checkbox-material .check:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 inset;
  animation: checkbox-off 0.3s forwards;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:focus + .checkbox-material .check:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-material .check {
  background: #9c27b0;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-material .check:before {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px, 10px -10px 0 10px, 32px 0 0 20px, 0px 32px 0 20px, -5px 5px 0 10px, 20px -12px 0 11px;
  animation: checkbox-on 0.3s forwards;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-material:before {
  animation: rippleOn 500ms;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-material .check:after {
  animation: rippleOn 500ms forwards;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + .checkbox-material:before {
  animation: rippleOff 500ms;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + .checkbox-material .check:after {
  animation: rippleOff 500ms;
}
fieldset[disabled] .checkbox, fieldset[disabled] .checkbox input[type=checkbox],
.checkbox input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ .checkbox-material .check,
.checkbox input[type=checkbox][disabled] + .circle {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ .checkbox-material .check {
  border-color: #000000;
  opacity: .26;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox][disabled] + .checkbox-material .check:after {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.87);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes checkbox-on {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px, 10px -10px 0 10px, 32px 0 0 20px, 0px 32px 0 20px, -5px 5px 0 10px, 15px 2px 0 11px;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px, 10px -10px 0 10px, 32px 0 0 20px, 0px 32px 0 20px, -5px 5px 0 10px, 20px 2px 0 11px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px, 10px -10px 0 10px, 32px 0 0 20px, 0px 32px 0 20px, -5px 5px 0 10px, 20px -12px 0 11px;
  }
}
@keyframes rippleOn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes rippleOff {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[image: radiobutton]
[image: checkbox]

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use `appearance` in your CSS:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  appearance:         none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I add this?

Comment: I edited my answer - you can add it to any form element to remove the default browser styling across various browsers. You can add this to `input[type=checkbox]` and/or `input[type=radio]`.

Comment: Oh - you're missing a font. The framework you're using requires a font, most likely either Glyphicons or FontAwesome. Check the installation instructions to see if you're installing the font correctly.

Comment: Strange that it works well on all devices (except iOS). Where does it take the font for them? ... The instruction says nothing about the font. And the page I gave as example belongs to the developers of framework.

Comment: It looks like it extends Bootstrap, and Bootstrap requires Glyphicons. If one font is installed, it might work in some places but not others - multiple font files are required to support multiple browsers. However, I can't see any code, so I don't really know if that's what's happening.

Comment: If it works with their code but not in yours, their code won't help much.

Comment: It doesn't work with their code. http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/documentation/tutorial-components.html#checkbox-row - is their official webpage and it doesn't work there.

Comment: File a bug report?

Comment: Did it a few days ago - no answer, so I am trying to find some other way to fix it ;)